# UISplitViewController - replace back-chevron icon with a sidebar toggle icon in portrait

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working on an iPadOS app in which I use `UISplitViewController`. So far I have been using old APIs and handling everything (including the `displayModeButtonItem`) manually. Now I wanted to migrate to the newer "column style" APIs (`super.init(style: .doubleColumn`). I had a few UI issues, but I managed to fix them with a few workarounds, but now I'm blocked on an issue for which I can't find any solution:

I'd like to make use of all built-in mechanisms of the iOS14's `UISplitViewController`, so I set `presentsWithGesture` property to `true`. Because of this I get sidebar toggle icon in landscape orientation (which works exactly how I want it), but in portrait I get a "back-chevron icon" with "back" title. Is there a way to force sidebar toggle icon to be displayed for both orientations?

[image: Portrait orientation - I'd like to have sidebar toggle icon here]

[image: Landscape orientation - this is how I'd like the button to look like in both orientations]

Comment: About 16 months ago (while iPadOS 14 was in beta) I tried something similar. It seems that the default behavior on (at least) an iPad using both Primary *and* Secondary VCs is to "hide" or close the PrimaryVC when rotating from landscape to portrait. My *first* workaround was to flag things and force the Primary to stay visible no matter what. This made things too complicated to maintain, so I went in a very different direction - only have a Secondary (and Compact) VC and roll my own Primary. In your case, that would at least give you the same nav bar in all orientations. Not optimal I know.

Comment: @dfd Actually I want the sidebar to be closed in portrait and work as an overlay (instead of another column) in this orientation. The only issue I have is the appearance of the button in portrait. The “back chevron” is much less clear for the app users in my app context. It might make sense for other apps, but not for mine, so I’d like to display the sidebar button in both orientations.

Comment: Then you may need to do two things. (1) Determine when orientation changes on the iPad. Do not forget that when your app is in full screen, it will *always* show a Regular size class, and when it's in split screen - multi-tasking - it *may* use the Compact size class depending on screen size, orientation, and how much area your app is using. (2) Determine which nav bar is being shown - if any, as when displaying the Compact VC a UISplitViewController doesn't provide one by default. IIRC, when displaying the Primary VC, two nav bars are displayed. Provide your own nav bar button as desired.

Comment: @dfd Any ideas how I should provide the nav bar button? I tried setting it like this: ‘self.viewController(for: secondary)?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(…’, but this has no effect at all. The standard back button is visible, but my custom one is not.

Answer (score 1):

I set up a sample project and I'm not getting the behavior you are. I'm thinking it's because we do things differently in setting up the `UISplitViewController`.

First, a major thanks to Matt Neuburg (@matt here on SO) for his two part article. ([part one here](https://www.biteinteractive.com/split-view-controllers-done-right-in-ios-14/)) This provided me with some big changes to my code.

Basically, I no longer set my `UISplitViewController` to be the root view in my scenes. Instead, I do not touch `SceneDelegate` at all, but use the default `ViewController`:

```
let primaryVC = PrimaryVC()
let secondaryVC = SecondaryVC()
let compactVC = CompactVC()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let split = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
    self.addChild(split)
    self.view.addSubview(split.view)
    split.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    split.presentsWithGesture = true
    split.preferredSplitBehavior = .tile
    split.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    split.didMove(toParent: self)
    split.setViewController(primaryVC, for: .primary)
    split.setViewController(secondaryVC, for: .secondary)
    split.setViewController(compactVC, for: .compact)
}
```

When I do this, I get a "sidebar.left" button and no "Back" button with Chevron. I'm using Xcode 13.1 and tried this with targets of iPadOS 14.0 and 15.1.

If you need to add/replace a bar button, what I do is:

var barBtnSidebarLeft = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName:"sidebar.left"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(leftSidebarTapped))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnSidebarLeft

But beware that if you do this, you will get *two* sidebar buttons! With regards to bar buttons, one more note - while the `UISplitViewController` provides a navigation bar *by* default for Primary and Secondary, it *does not* for Compact. (Frankly, I don't think it's good practice to have one when in compact size.)

Finally, read through the link I provided. It really gets into using `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` to help you pass along your scene state values properly. (I prefer calling it scene state instead of app state because iPads can have multiple app windows.)

**EDIT**

One last thought. IIRC you *can* do this:

- set `presentsWithGesture` to `false
- place your own bar buttons as pleased in both view controllers
- manually (through the delegate functions?) open and close the Primary view controller